# updating an installed windows 8 32 bit to windows 8 64 bit

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

Just got myself a new Windows 8 tablet, which operates a 32 bit Win 8 (It was advertised as 64 bit on amazon, but that's another subject I guess).
My question is, can I upgrade the existing system to 64 bit, without having to set up win 8 again? I haven't found anything on google, not even someone with the same question which makes me kind of afraid there is no solution.. Anyway, here I am and ask :) 
Any answers are kindly appreciated ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no upgrade path when changing architecture, so no, you will have to do a complete reinstall when switching from 32bit to 64bit, no matter what hardware you are on.

Your data will be lost if you do not backup manually, all programs and drivers will need to be re-installed.To quote Microsofts official documentation:

> If you want to move from a 32-bit version of Windows to a 64-bit version of Windows 7 or vice versa, you'll need to back up your files and choose the Custom option during Windows 7 installation. Then, you'll need to restore your files and reinstall your programs.